# Rebus secondlevel retry, specify number of retry for message

Tags: rebus

Is it possible to specify / override the number of second level retries, for specific messages?

Some messages are more important to try to execute than others or need to try over a longer time period because of the nature of the message.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, there will be as many 2nd level retries as there were 1st level retries.

But now that you're asking and you made me think about this, I think it would actually make much more sense to **not** have a fixed number of 2nd level retries.... instead I'm thinking that the 2nd level mechanism should be *one single attempt* of dispatching the message to handlers as a `Failed<TMessage>`, and then you can defer the message and count 2nd level delivery attempts in a message header if you like.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I agree second level usually means that the service that the message is interacting with is down, and that it probably is not available after the next 10 seconds. Then you decide based on the message how long between each retry, and how many. That makes sense to me.